# Deploying container image to Azure Service fabric without packaging it

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to deploy container image to service fabric cluster without packaging it?

Comment: Hi there - you'll get the most benefit from this site by first attempting what your wanting to do and then asking for help on any of the bugs you'll encounter.

Comment: unsure what you mean by packaging, but maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. What do you mean by packaging? See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux

Comment: When we deploy application to service fabric cluster we first package the application. Packaging creates an suitable architecture that makes it easy for application to run on cluster

Comment: Service Fabric does not require your code to run in containers, so they are not needed. If you want your code to run in a container, Service Fabric does not have features to build it for you.